# Azure Blob Storage metrics with MetricsQueryClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I can connect to Azure Blob Storage with c# API BlobServiceClient and connection string from account "access keys".

Is it anyway I can reuse this to create c# API MetricsQueryClient?

BlobServiceClient allows to connect using SAS token or account key, unfortunately MetricsQueryClient provides different way for authorization. Trying to understand if storage account SAS/Key can we utilized to connect using MetricsQueryClient and collect account usage metrics.

Answer (score 0):

The [`MetricsQueryClient` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.monitor.query.metricsqueryclient?view=azure-dotnet)

> allows you to query the Azure Monitor Metrics service.

This has nothing to do with Storage. The idea behind storage providing access via a SAS tokens is that

> A shared access signature (SAS) provides secure delegated access to resources in your storage account. With a SAS, you have granular control over how a client can access your data.

If you want to allow other parties to connect to Azure Monitor, please have a look at storing the data elsewhere and providing access there.

If you really want to allow external access to an Azure Monitor instance you might want to have a look at using a dedicated Service Principal.

More information, see [Roles, permissions, and security in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/roles-permissions-security).

Comment: Hi @rickvdbosch, thank you for your response. My current goal is to start colleting storage account usage metrics. I'm able to get API access via BlobServiceClient using SAS or even account connection string. I wonder if I can collect metrics using this API and credentials?